How long can swans hold their breath?
I’m curious if anyone has information or literature on the maximum duration that swans can hold their breath while submerged. Specifically, I’m interested in how long species like the Mute Swan or Whooper Swan can stay underwater during a dive. Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated!
